# Python max(date) in list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to return the max date in a list from a bs4 scrape. Here's what I've got so far..

```
import requests
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

con = requests.get("https://au.investing.com/currencies/aud-usd-historical-data/",
               headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
odcon = OrderedDict()
content_page = soup(con.content, 'html.parser')
table = content_page.find('table', {'class': 'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'})
cols = [th.text for th in table.select("th")[1:]]
for row in table.select("tbody tr"):
    data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
    data[0] = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    print(max(data[0]))



Output looks like this for print(data[0])
13/09/2018
12/09/2018
11/09/2018
10/09/2018
09/09/2018
07/09/2018
06/09/2018
05/09/2018
04/09/2018
03/09/2018
02/09/2018
31/08/2018
30/08/2018
29/08/2018
28/08/2018
27/08/2018
26/08/2018
24/08/2018
23/08/2018
22/08/2018
21/08/2018
20/08/2018
19/08/2018
17/08/2018
16/08/2018
15/08/2018
14/08/2018
13/08/2018
```

I would like the max date in this list to be returned/printed.

This is probably an easy solve.. but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens? And what should happen?

Comment: If you have the date displayed in day-month-year order, and you're doing a lexographical (alphabetical) sort, it will never come out right. If you can, you need to reverse the date format to YYYY/MM/DD, or else convert it into a datetime.datetime type

Comment: What's happened is that the strftime makes it a string. Removing that makes it a date so the max should then work as expected.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help and explanation. Was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this mod to your code

```
dateList = []

for row in table.select("tbody tr"):
    data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
    d = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%b %d, %Y').date()
    dateList = dateList + [d, ]

print max(dateList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. Your code is returning "31/08/2018", which is the max day value. So I guess that means it's not looking at the date as a full date? I had the same problem with some of my other attempts to get the max date value in this list.

Comment: Your data has only data at a date granularity. Were you expecting time as well? Cos it is not in the data you are scraping. If not, not sure what you mean by a full date.

Comment: In my previous comment, by full date I meant DD/MM/YYYY. 
As I mentioned, when I ran the code it returned 31/08/2018, so I assumed it's only looking at the '31' when it returned as max(). I'm looking for "13/09/2018" to be returned.

Comment: Ahhh,,, I see what you mean... I will mod the answer with the following

    d = datetime.strptime(data[0], '%b %d, %Y').date()

Answer (score 0):

format the date after sorting the list of the dates:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
site = requests.get("https://au.investing.com/currencies/aud-usd-historical-data/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
content_page = bs4(site.content, 'html.parser')
table = content_page.find('table', {'class': 'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'})
cols = [th.text for th in table.select("th")[1:]]

dates = []
for row in table.select("tbody tr"):
    data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
    dates.append(data[0])
dates.sort()
datetime.strptime(max(dates), '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

output:

```
'13/09/2018'
```

BTW, `cols` isn't being used here.